# Forwarding all Kubernetes traffic through a single node

Tags: kubernetes, networking, flannel

I have a Kubernetes cluster with multiple nodes in two different subnets (`x` and `y`). I have an IPsec VPN tunnel setup between my `x` subnet and an external network. Now my problem is that the pods that get scheduled in the nodes on the `y` subnet can't send requests to the external network because they're in nodes not covered by the VPN tunnel. Creating another VPN to cover the `y` subnet isn't possible right now. Is there a way in k8s to force all pods' traffic to go through a single source? Or any clean solution even if outside of k8s?

Comment: What kind of services are in external network? Are they well know and defined? I mean are there exact services or in general? Asking because [istio gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/) can be helpful here to direct all traffic though `gateway` pod which would be deployed on node in subnet x and traffic will go inside the cluster between nodes in both subnets.

Comment: Also you may consider another solution - [antrea egress](https://antrea.io/docs/v1.4.0/docs/egress/) - "When a selected Pod accesses the external network, the egress traffic will be tunneled to the Node that hosts the egress IP if it’s different from the Node that the Pod runs on and will be SNATed to the egress IP when leaving that Node."

Comment: With kubernetes native features, you can't force egress through a specific node, and I believe there are several ways to do this externally or installing other tools, like istio, but if you want it done only with kubernetes, you can force these services to be deployed on a specific node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

There is no built-in functionality in kubernetes that can do it. However there are two available options which can help to achieve the required setup:

1. **Istio**

If services are well known then it's possible to use [istio egress gateway](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/). We are interested in this use case:

> Another use case is a cluster where the application nodes don’t have
> public IPs, so the in-mesh services that run on them cannot access the
> Internet. Defining an egress gateway, directing all the egress traffic
> through it, and allocating public IPs to the egress gateway nodes
> allows the application nodes to access external services in a
> controlled way.

2. **Antrea egress**

There's another solution which can be used - [antrea egress](https://antrea.io/docs/v1.4.0/docs/egress/). Use cases are:

You may be interested in using this capability if any of the following apply:

> - A consistent IP address is desired when specific Pods connect to
>   services outside of the cluster, for source tracing in audit logs, or
>   for filtering by source IP in external firewall, etc.
> - You want to force outgoing external connections to leave the cluster
>   via certain Nodes, for security controls, or due to network topology
>   restrictions.